# Extract node into a variable where elements meet a match

Tags: xml, xslt

Pretty new to using Xslt and I am trying to extract a node if 2 elements meet a match. Here is a sample of the XML

```
<resultset>
  <row>
    <Abs>1</Abs>
    <Real>1</Real>
    <Let>A</Let>
    <pdate>2014-09-22</pdate>
    <Id>11913</Id>
  </row>
<row>
    <Abs>2</Abs>
    <Real>2</Real>
    <Let>A</Let>
    <pdate>2014-09-22</pdate>
    <Id>11914</Id>
  </row>
<row>
    <Abs>3</Abs>
    <Real>3</Real>
    <Let>A</Let>
    <pdate>2014-09-22</pdate>
    <Id>11915</Id>
  </row>
</resultset>
```

Here is my xslt

```
   <xsl:param name="p_data_file">/tmp/pdata.xml</xsl:param>
    <xsl:for-each select="file">
    <xsl:sort select="sec"/>
    <xsl:sort select="page" data-type="number"/>
    <xsl:variable name="sec" select="sec/text()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="page" select="page/text()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="p_data" select="document($p_data_file)/resultset/row[field[@name='Let
']=$sec and field[@name='Real']=$page]"/>
```

I can see that sec and page are being set A 1, A 2, A 3 but, p_data never gets set. Am I completely off or just missing something?

Any help or pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please post a minimal but **complete** example of your XML and XSLT. For example, there's no `file` element in your XML input - so `<xsl:for-each select="file">` will not return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it's a bit guessing: If it's only about the p_data variable, the select-value may need to be adjusted:

```
<xsl:variable name="p_data" 
 select="document($p_data_file)/resultset/
 row[field[@name='Let']=$sec and field[@name='Real']=$page]"/>
```

should be

```
<xsl:variable name="p_data"
 select="document($p_data_file)/resultset/
  row[child::Let/text()=$sec and child::Real/text()=$page]"/>
```

Just tested this starting from //row and selected a specific one:

```
//row[child::Let/text()='A' and child::Real/text()='2']
```

Result:

```
<row>
 <Abs>2</Abs>
 <Real>2</Real>
 <Let>A</Let>
 <pdate>2014-09-22</pdate>
 <Id>11914</Id>
</row>
```